# Crop UIImage into a square after taking it - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, avfoundation

```
 var image = UIImagePickerController()
 image.delegate = self
 image.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
 image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
 image.allowsEditing = false
 self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is the code I am using. I need to take that image, whether it was taken in landscape or portrait and resize it to a perfect square. Simply setting allowsEditing to true doesn't work because if it is taken in landscape, it doesn't crop correctly and has a black bar at the top. I am really confused as to how to do this.

The perfect example of an application that does this is Instagram or specifically Vine. I need every picture posted to be a perfect square. Thank you!

Comment: image.allowsEditing = true

Comment: The problem is not with cropping but with imageView contentMode. Try this in your imageview code: `imageview.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill` along with `image.allowsEditing = true`

Comment: I wish that worked but it did not.